# Game screen with play area on the left and UI fixed on the right

Tags: libgdx

I am struggling with implementing a game screen with 2 stages.
the intention is for the left area say 50% to be play area and 50% to the right area for UI stuff.

So far I have this:

```
class GameScreen implements Screen { 

     Stage playStage;
     Stage uiStage;

     private GameScreen() {
         // this is a 1024 * 768 resolution game

         Viewport playVP = new FitViewPort(512, 768, new OrthographicCamera());

         playStage = new Stage(playVP);
         playVP.setScreenBounds(0,0,512,768);

         Viewport uiVP = new FitViewPort(512, 768, new OrthographicCamera());

         uiStage = new Stage(uiVP);
         uiVP.setScreenBounds(512,0,512,768); // offset the x

     }

     public void render(float delta) {
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

         playStage.act();
         uiStage.act();

         playrenderer.setView(playCamera);
         playrenderer.render();

         uiRenderer.setView(uiCamera);
         uiRenderer.render();

         playStage.draw();
         uiStage.draw();
     }
}
```

The uiRenderer seems to be overlay on top of the play area, rather than situated fixed to the right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will have to create a custom viewport subclass if you don't want a centered viewport. All the built-in ones support centered positioning only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use apply method after set bounds.

```
vp.apply(boolean centercamera)
```

or just

```
vp.apply()
```

since you dont want to center to camera.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! tks!